# Bash echo -e equivalent using sed and tee

Tags: bash

I am doing some find/replace thing with `sed` and using `tee`  to write output file.Here is the command

```
    # $1 source
    # $2 Type
    # $3 name 
    # $4 body 

    sudo sed  "s/<!--ID-->/1/g"  ./templates/tpl.txt \
        | sed  "s/<!--AUTHOR-->/myname/g"  \
        | sed  "s/<!--TYPE-->/$2/g"  \
        | sed  "s/<!--BODY-->/$4/g"  \
        | sed  "s/<!--NAME-->/$3/g"  \
        | tee  "$3.txt" > /dev/null
```

In the output file I see "n" in place of new lines . I need the same effect of as of the following
(but after template substitution )

```
 echo -e "$4" > "$3.txt"
```

I am bash learner and please help me furnish my code

## Edit

$4 contains multiline string (e.g a mysql [function /procedure or trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) ) with  comments etc

thanks

Comment: Which version of `sed`, `bash` and which OS are you using?

Comment: my bash version is `GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0) Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
` , don't know  how to check sed version

Comment: Ok, you could try my last added version (for Mac)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan to use `tee` for writting privileged files, you have to use `sudo` with `tee`.

You could:

```
sed < template/tpl.txt -e "
    s/<!--ID-->/1/g;
    s/<!--AUTHOR-->/myname/g;
    s/<!--TYPE-->/$2/g;
    s/<!--NAME-->/$3/g;
    /<!--BODY-->/{s/<!--BODY-->/$4/;s/\\n/\n/g;}
  " | sudo tee "$3" >/dev/null
```

other way: in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) ,you could use:

```
echo "${4//\\n/$'\n'}"
```

so:

```
sed "s/<!--BODY-->/${4//\\n/$'\n'}/;"
```

could work too.

With Mac's `sed` this may work better:

```
sed < template/tpl.txt "s/<\!--ID-->/1/g;
     s/<\!--AUTHOR-->/myname/g;
     s/<\!--TYPE-->/$2/g;
     s/<\!--BODY-->/${4//\\n/\\$'\n'}/
  " | sudo tee "$3" >/dev/null
```

Explanation: `${4//\\n/\\$'\n'}` are *bashism*, we could use as you use [bash](/questions/tagged/bash). Mac sed don't support `\n` as newline, but support a newline if escaped by a backslash `\`, so in *RHS*, `\n` could be written (in bash): `\\$'\n'` :

```
echo abc\\$'\n'def
abc\
def
```

Comment: how about other special characters e.g LF/CRLF and tabs ?

Comment: I am not understanding this part : `/<!--BODY-->/{s/<!--BODY-->/$4/;s/\\n/\n/g;}`

Comment: It's an *operation block* delimited by `{...}`, to be executed at location, where `/.../` match. U could *replace* `grep blah` by: `sed -ne "/blah/p"` for sample.

Comment: I tried sht like this `body=$(echo -e "$4")` and `output=$(sed -e "s/<!--ID-->/$changesetID/g" ./templates/mysql_obj.xml \
      |sed  "s/<!--AUTHOR-->/$author/g"  \
     |sed  "s/<!--TYPE-->/$2/g"  \
     |sed  "s/<!--BODY-->/$body/"  \
     |sed  "s/<!--NAME-->/$3/g" );`

Comment: and output is `sed: 1: "s/<!--BODY-->/CREAT ...": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern
`

Comment: With Mac' sed, try this: `sed "s/<\!--BODY-->/${4//\\n/\\$'\n'}/"`